# Compare between columns on different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, compare

I need to write T-SQL code that will compare between `T1.PercentComplete` that need to be between `T2.StageFrom` and `T2.StageTo`. and than get the `T2.Bonus_Prec` and join T1

**T1:**
 
[image]

**T2:**
[image]

The desired result for `T2.Bonus_Prec` is `0.02` since `T1.Percent_Complete` is `.27`, which is between `0` and `1`.

The thing is that each `Key` can have a different `T2.StageID` between 1-6.
If `Key` have just one `T2.StageID` it'll be 0.  (fast way for me to know that there is only 1 bonus option)
If it have more than 1 it's will start with 1. (This can be changed if needed)

T1:

`DROP TABLE T1;
CREATE TABLE T1(
   Key    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,Percent_Complete_ NUMBER(16,2) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO T1(Key,Percent_Complete_) VALUES ('Key Vendor',Percent_Complete);
INSERT INTO T1(Key,Percent_Complete_) VALUES ('***',0.27);`

T2:
`DROP TABLE T2;
CREATE TABLE T2(
   Key    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  ,StageID INT  NOT NULL
  ,Stage_From NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL
  ,Stage_To NUMERIC(8,2) NOT NULL
  ,Stage_Bonus_Prec NUMERIC(16,2) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO T2(Key,StageID,Stage_From,Stage_To,Stage_Bonus_Prec) VALUES ('Key',Stage_Id,Stage_From,Stage_To,Stage_Bonus_Prec);
INSERT INTO T2(Key,StageID,Stage_From,Stage_To,Stage_Bonus_Prec) VALUES ('***',1,0,0.8,0.02);
INSERT INTO T2(Key,StageID,Stage_From,Stage_To,Stage_Bonus_Prec) VALUES ('***',2,0.8,1,0.035);
INSERT INTO T2(Key,StageID,Stage_From,Stage_To,Stage_Bonus_Prec) VALUES ('***',3,1,-1,0.05);`

OUTPUT:
`+-----+-------------------+--------------------+
| Key | Percent_Complete  | [Stage_Bonus_Prec] |
+-----+-------------------+--------------------+
| *** | 0.27              | 0.02               |
+-----+-------------------+--------------------+`

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4927d) with these values

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I hope it's better now. Thanks

Comment: There is nothing like posting consumable ddl and sample data. And this is nothing like consumable ddl and sample data. The challenge here is that we don't know what you are trying to do, we don't know your tables and we can't see you screen. The only thing we know is what you have posted which at this point is pretty much nothing. Did you notice the part in the article I referenced about posting the create table statements and insert statements for sample data? If you do that we can help, otherwise there is nothing we can do.

Comment: That's why I changed the post and add the 2 tables images, this is what I see and this is all the data right now.

Comment: You didn't add two tables. You added two pictures. We don't know the datatypes of anything and more importantly we can't run this on our system so we can create the query. Even with that we have no idea what you expect for output based on these two tables because there are no rules posted.

Comment: You say `If key have just one t2.stageid it'll be 0`. You have the field "Key" in both tables, I assume to join on them. This `key` in both your sample tables in your pictures does not have a value of `1` or `0`. What do you mean that a `key` can have a different `t2.stageid` between 1 and 6, and furthermore is this `key` you are referring to now, a new `key` that is part of the record set of your desired result? As @SeanLange has pointed out example tables, data, and **desired results** are important to be able to help. Otherwise we are flying blind.

Comment: I'm also a bit confused about your `Key` field in both tables. Is the value actually `LEN...'? Since it sounds like `Key` is critical to the desired results, I think it would be important to see the full value.

Comment: No problem about the values but your ddl and sample data don't work. You defined State_Bonus_Perc as numeric(16,0) but you have decimal places. I will tweak this into something usable but you really should pay attention to these details. You also have extra rows of gibberish in your inserts and some of them don't work because they are syntactically incorrect.

Comment: I can't show the real key because of customer need and privacy.
Yes I join the 2 tables with the Key column.

What I mean that each key can have 1 or more levels of calculating the bonus  and it's define by `t2.stageid`. If a key have only  one level than `t2.stageid` is 0 (fast way for me to know that there is only 1 bonus option.)   If a key have more than one level that `t2.stageid` will start with 1 and and can be stop at 2,3,4,5,6. (6 is the max level)

I fixed the code. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is still not clear what you are trying to do but I made an attempt. Please notice I also corrected a number of issues with ddl and sample data you posted.

```
if OBJECT_ID('T1') is not null
    drop table T1

CREATE TABLE T1(
   KeyVendor VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,PercentComplete VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO T1(KeyVendor,PercentComplete) VALUES ('***','0.27');

if OBJECT_ID('T2') is not null
    drop table T2

CREATE TABLE T2(
   MyKey    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  ,StageID INT  NOT NULL
  ,Stage_From NUMERIC(10,0) NOT NULL
  ,Stage_To NUMERIC(8,0) NOT NULL
  ,Stage_Bonus_Prec NUMERIC(16,3) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO T2(MyKey,StageID,Stage_From,Stage_To,Stage_Bonus_Prec) VALUES ('***',1,0,0.8,0.02);
INSERT INTO T2(MyKey,StageID,Stage_From,Stage_To,Stage_Bonus_Prec) VALUES ('***',2,0.8,1,0.035);
INSERT INTO T2(MyKey,StageID,Stage_From,Stage_To,Stage_Bonus_Prec) VALUES ('***',3,1,-1,0.05);

select * 
from T1
cross apply 
(
    select top 1 Stage_Bonus_Prec 
    from T2 
    where t1.PercentComplete >= t2.Stage_Bonus_Prec 
        and t1.KeyVendor = t2.MyKey 
    order by Stage_Bonus_Prec
) x
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll Try this and report here.

If it's still not clear I will try to do that simple.

I have bonus table(T2) with bonus level (between 1-6, can be 1-2 , or 1-4)  and performance Table(T1)
I want to get the `Stage_Bonus_Prec` from the table according to the performance T1 `PercentComplete`

Answer (score 0):

Taking a shot at this as well, since it's still a bit unclear:

```
SELECT t1.percent_complete, t2.Stage_Bonus_Prec
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 
  ON T1.[key vendor] = T2.[Key] AND
    T1.[percent_complete] BETWEEN T2.Stage_From AND T2.Stage_To
```

Joining `T1` and `T2` on `[Key Vendor]` and `[Key]` and using the `BETWEEN` operator to find the `percent_complete` value that is between `Stage_From` and `Stage_To`.

I think I'm still missing something since I'm still confused about where `Key` value of `***` comes from in your desired results.

[SQLFiddle of this in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4927d/2), based on a slightly fixed up version of your DDL (you put your field names in their own data record, I've removed them since they don't belong there).